# C++ - interval tree implementation

Tags: c++, data-structures, interval-tree

*Does someone know any good `interval tree` implementation in C++?*

Obviously, something template-driven, better in `boost`-like style.

And another question - if somebody tested, does a basic `std::vector`-based interval tree implementation with sorting can beat the generic interval tree *(with O(lg) operations)* in practice?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Boost-like ? [Boost ICL](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/libs/icl/doc/html/index.html)!

*The Boost Interval Container Library*

Comment: Hm, nice timing from `boost`. I though current version was 1.45 and I didn't know I was so lucky. Thanks

Comment: @Yippie: just discovered it recently (by @ybungalobill I think) myself :)

Comment: If anyone knows why this answer has received one upvote and one downvote today after a few months of inactivity, I'd be really glad to learn about it!

Comment: I supplied a down vote, as the question is about interval trees, but this response only supplied a link to an interval container library in boost which doesn't have a query-tree implementation.  [This message on the boost mailing list indicates this deficiency, but no solution has been provided as of this date.](http://lists.boost.org/Archives/boost/2010/12/174073.php)  Of course, it seems the question author was satisfied with this response, so maybe I am just in need of a new question to reply to :)

Comment: @Erik: Thanks for the heads up! I admit I've never used Interval Trees (past the playground...) and I wrote them myself when reading the "Introduction to Algorithms". It's good to note that there are various needs in the manipulation.

Answer (score 22):

I had exactly the same need.  I couldn't find any suitable (simple, modern, portable) implementations, so I used [a python implementation by Brent Pedersen](http://hackmap.blogspot.com/2008/11/python-interval-tree.html) as a guide and wrote a barebones [C++ version](https://github.com/ekg/intervaltree).  The IntervalTree behaves like a standard STL container, with some caveats due to its simplicity (no iterators, for instance).  You use it like this ("T" is an arbitrary type):

```
vector<Interval<T> > intervals;
// ... make intervals!
IntervalTree<T> tree(intervals);
```

And you query it like this:

```
vector<Interval<T> > results;
tree.findContained(start, stop, results);
// results now contains Intervals which are fully contained in the query interval
results.clear();
tree.findOverlapping(start, stop, results);
// results now contains Intervals which overlap the query interval
```

Comment: Hi Erik thanks for pointing this. I am looking at your code and trying to relate to the theory (please bear in mind I am new to this.)`sanityIntervals.push_back(interval(60, 80, true));` and ` for (int i = 0; i < 10000; ++i) {
        intervals.push_back(randomInterval<bool>(100000, 1000, 100000 + 1, true));
    }`. I have been looking at fork-event-join models with id,event pairing. Can you elaborate how did you come up with those numbers - 60,80,etc and what is bool value chosen object? Say I have a distributed system - one server and multiple clients, how can I utilize your code?

Comment: Unfortunately, the find functions return a copy of the internal iterator which means a copy operation is needed for every query operation. This is very slow in a large application. While the code works but it's slow.

Comment: @SmallChess absolutely not. The whole point of returning by value in non flow-diverging functions such as this, is to be certain of NRVO (named return value optimization). Not to mention in some situations copy elision is flat mandatory by standard.

Answer (score 2):

There appears [to be one](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/IEB/ToolBox/CPP_DOC/doxyhtml/classCIntervalTree.html) in the [NCBI C++ Toolkit](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/IEB/ToolBox/CPP_DOC/).

Jury's still out on whether it's "good," though (and even whether it's template-driven; I'm still somewhat new to C++, so I'm not entirely sure that it is, but I suspect as much).

Answer (score 1):

I uploaded simple implementation of Interval Tree to github: https://github.com/coolsoftware/ITree

Look class itree in itree.h.

Answer (score 0):

if you don't mind translating a c# implementation to c++, goto http://code.google.com/p/intervaltree/ .based on an avl self balancing tree.