# classification for large range of numbers

Tags: c++, enums

I need to write a method which classifies large range of numbers.
I`ve write the enum whith identifies.

```
enum op {
  memLoad = 130,
  memStore,
  //etc
}
```

For some identifies I have a range ,for example `0-120 - are registers numbers`
I can`t add 121 such (register) identifiers one by one to the enum.
How do you advice to deal such identifiers (which are defined as a range)?
Thanks,

Comment: Is there a reason these need to be enumerated explicitly? Could you instead just write a function which returns the necessary information about a number?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think enum is not the right instrument for the problem you are trying to solve.

I would suggest using [interval tree](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5407814/c-interval-tree-implementation) to have as expressive and fast code.

Answer (score 0):

A more sophisticated way to achieve classification may be made ​​using neural networks, as [WEKA Classification](http://wekaclassalgos.sourceforge.net/).