# Interval Tree Using C++ STL <map> or <set>

Tags: algorithm, stl, tree, intervals, red-black-tree

I need a data structure that can perform the following three queries in log(n) where n is the range of numbers.

- insert(a,b) : Insert Interval [a,b].
- count(x) : Count number of intervals that contain the point x.
- remove(a,b) : Remove Interval [a,b] from the set of intervals.

I came across the interval trees and its implementation in C++ requires the use of Red Black Trees. 
I am trying to avoid making the tree from scratch, is there a way I can implement the c++ stl like `<map>` or `<set>` to perform these operations ?

EDIT
I realised that since all I need is the count of the intervals that contain a point, I used a Binary Indexed Tree, its implementation is simple and performs the above queries in O(log(n)) time.

Comment: Use The Boost Interval Container Library, see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5407814/c-interval-tree-implementation)

Comment: Boost ICL provides you with such data structures like interval_map and interval_set.

Comment: I am aware of those. But I cannot use external libraries. I have to make my own implementation. I was hoping to reduce code size by implementing the STL.

Comment: If you have solved this problem, can you please post an answer to your own question and then accept it? That way, the question is actually marked as closed.

Comment: There was no solution to this problem. I had to workaround it by using a combination of Segment Tree and Binary Indexed Tree.